# On Regular Epimorphisms

Tags: category-theory

Sorry for my silly doubt. It is well known that in the category of sets and functions ${\bf Sets}$ epimorphisms are regular. Hence, every epimorphism is the coequalizer of two parallel arrows. Must these arrows must be necessarily distinct?

Consider in fact the isomorphism $\emptyset: \emptyset \longrightarrow \emptyset$. In such a case, it only coequalizes the pair $(\emptyset,\emptyset)$ of parallel functions - the previous are the empty maps. -

Therefore, it seems that parallel arrows could agree. But, in such a case, in general, is it not always true that a morphism $f$ coequalizes any pair of parallel arrows $(t,t)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any category we have that $f$ is the coequaliser of an equal pair of arrows iff $f$ is an isomorphism.

For one direction you simply verify that for any arrow $g: X \to Y$ the identity $Id_Y$ on $Y$ is the coequaliser of $g, g$.

For the other direction, if $f$ is an isomorphism then in particular it is a monomorphism. So if $f$ coequalises $g$ and $g'$ then $fg = fg'$, which implies $g =  g'$.

So to answer your original motivating question: the arrows $g,g'$ for which a surjective function $f$ of sets is the coequaliser are distinct precisely when $f$ is not an isomorphism (i.e. when $f$ is not injective).